# No me funciona el segundo else "if("descendente".equals(orden))"

Tags: java, condiciones

Es un programa muy facil pero soy nuevo en esto el ejercico es el siguiente:
Realiza un programa que lea dos valores y los
orden ascende o descentemente según elija el
usuario.

```
if("ascendente".equals(orden)){
    if(numero1 <= numero2){
        System.out.println(" " + numero1 + " , " + numero2);
    } else if("ascendente".equals(orden)){
        if(numero1 >= numero2){
            System.out.println(" " + numero2 + " , " + numero1);
        }else if("descendente".equals(orden)){
            if(numero1 >= numero2){
                System.out.println(" " + numero1 + " , " + numero2);
            }else if("descendente".equals(orden)){
                if(numero1 <= numero2){
                    System.out.println(" " + numero2 + " , " + numero1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}else{
    System.out.println("Error!");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analicemos el código:

```java
if("ascendente".equals(orden)){
   //Si estamos aquí, es que orden es "ascendente"
    if(numero1 <= numero2){
        //Si estamos aquí, orden es ascendente y n1 < n2
        System.out.println(" " + numero1 + " , " + numero2);
    } else if("ascendente".equals(orden)){
        // esta comprobación es redundante, siempre será "ascendente"
        if(numero1 >= numero2){ 
          // comprobación redundante: si estamos aquí es porque no se cumplio que n1 <= n2
            System.out.println(" " + numero2 + " , " + numero1);
        }else if("descendente".equals(orden)){ //siempre será falso!
            //todo este bloque es código "muerto", no se ejecutará nunca
            if(numero1 >= numero2){
                System.out.println(" " + numero1 + " , " + numero2);
            }else if("descendente".equals(orden)){
                if(numero1 <= numero2){
                    System.out.println(" " + numero2 + " , " + numero1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}else{
    System.out.println("Error!");
}
```

Por tanto podrías limpiar un poco tus condiciones y hacer algo como

```java
if("ascendente".equals(orden)){
  if (n1 > n2) {
    ...
  } else { //n1 <= n2
    ...
  }
} else { // es descendente
    if (n1 > n2) {
    ...
  } else { //n1 <= n2
    ...
  }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Según lo veo te enredaste en un problema de lógica, siempre es mejor ver que se quiere lograr y como seria la simplificación del problema, sin pensar tanto en el código que vas a escribir:

```
Ascendente: MENOR -> MAYOR
Descendente: MAYOR -> MENOR
```

Si al ordenar los valores fuesen iguales no importaría el orden de impresión, esa seria la forma de verlo.

Ascendente:

```
// MENOR -> MAYOR
    
if(orden.equals("ascendente")) {
    if(numero1 <= numero2) {
        System.out.println(numero1 + ", " + numero2);
    }else{
        System.out.println(numero2 + ", " + numero1);
    }
}
```

Descendente:

```
// MAYOR -> MENOR
    
if(orden.equals("descendente")) {
    if(numero1 >= numero2) {
        System.out.println(numero1 + ", " + numero2);
    }else{
        System.out.println(numero2 + ", " + numero1);
    }
}
```

Para ejecutar, tomo 2 valores numéricos y pasan por las condiciones tomando en cuenta el orden.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numero1 = 7;
    int numero2 = 4;
    
    String orden = "ascendente";
    
    // MENOR -> MAYOR
    
    if(orden.equals("ascendente")) {
        if(numero1 <= numero2) {
            System.out.println(numero1 + ", " + numero2);
        }else{
            System.out.println(numero2 + ", " + numero1);
        }
    }
    
    // MAYOR -> MENOR
    
    if(orden.equals("descendente")) {
        if(numero1 >= numero2) {
            System.out.println(numero1 + ", " + numero2);
        }else{
            System.out.println(numero2 + ", " + numero1);
        }
    }
    
}
```